# how to prevent xss in GmailMessage.getBody() print

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I'm building a Google Script Web App that uses the user's Gmail messages
(I'm using the built-in gmail api), when the user chooses a message, I want to show him the message's content, to asure that's the right message.
I'm afraid the mail might contain xss, but I don't want to loose the styling of the message, it's ugly, so I can't write

```
var output=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("");
output.appendUntrusted(message.getPlainBody());
```

my current Code is:

```
function getMessageContent(message)
{
   var output=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("");
   output.append(message.getBody());
   return output;
}
```

does a mail really might include xss?
If the answer is yes, how can I prevent it?

thanks Noam.

Comment: Send the email to yourself then you will know?

Comment: I checked it, the xss works very well, so the question is how to prevent it...